# Google Maps - search POINTS circle in MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, maps

I have a problem, namely, I need to check if a given location (street) is in a given district. Data is saved to the database on the basis of this:

```js
let latLng = currentCircle.getCenter();
let circleCenter = latLng.lat() + ' ' + latLng.lng();
let radius = currentCircle.getRadius();
```

[image]

To gets lat and lng I use:

[image]

On the JS side for lat and lng download I use:

```js
const position = googleMaps.initPlace().getGPS();
const positions = {
   lat: position.lat,
   lng: position.lng,
}
```

I send the above data to PHP, which must check whether these points are in one of the areas:

```sql
SELECT id, title, radius, ST_X(center) as lat, ST_Y(center) as lng
FROM shop_zones
WHERE ST_PointFromText(center, POINT(?, ?))
```

Unfortunately, the above query returns nothing each time.

**Thanks in advance for any help.**

Comment: Is 'district' synonymous with 'circle'?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `where` condition in your SQL script is not correct for your intent.

You need to find out the points that intersect the circle area.
Take a look at the [st_intersects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html) function.
This should do the job.